# Executing Athena Query from python code using boto3 shows error "botocore.errorfactory.InvalidRequestException"

Tags: boto3, amazon-athena

I am executing Athena query using the boto3 library as per the given code below:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('athena')

def main():
    queryStart = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString = 'SELECT * FROM <tablename>',
        QueryExecutionContext = {
            'Database': '<databasename>'
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': 's3://<outputlocation>',
        'EncryptionConfiguration': {
            'EncryptionOption': 'SSE_S3'
        }
     }
    )
    queryExecution = client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId=queryStart['QueryExecutionId'],MaxResults=10)
    prinnt(queryExecution)
```

While executing this simple code I am getting the error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "readingathena.py", line 38, in <module>
      main()
      File "readingathena.py", line 33, in main
      for i in response_iterator:
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\botocore\paginate.py", line 255, in __iter__
      response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\botocore\paginate.py", line 332, in _make_request
return self._method(**current_kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 357, in _api_call
      return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
      raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
      botocore.errorfactory.InvalidRequestException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the GetQueryResults operation: Query has not yet finished. Current state: RUNNING
```

The thing I want to achieve is to get the result printed on console instead of getting it in store in s3 location.

P.S the output is stored in S3 bucket despite the error. But not able to get the response using function **"get_query_results"**

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to get query results until the query has completed, i.e. the state is `SUCCEEDED`. You have to use the `get_query_execution` API call to poll for the state, until it is `SUCCEEDED` and only then call `get_query_results`.

There is also, unfortunately, no way to get the result without it being stored on S3. This is the way Athena is designed, and there is no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, I fixed only by adding the policy "AmazonS3FullAccess" to the role that Lambda is using.